# Test a button click using protractor in angularjs app

Tags: javascript

```
describe("holiday calendar", function() {
 var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
 ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
 var elem=ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('holidayId'));
 elem.click().then(function(){
     ptor.waitForAngular();
     it('holiday list length', function() {
        var list = element.all(by.repeater('holiday in holidayList'));
        expect(list.count()).toEqual(10);
     });
 });
});
```

i am getting the following error:-

```
var template = new Error(this.message);
ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=36.0.1985.125)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 3.8.0-44-generic x86_64)
   at new bot.Error (/home/sanjay/Documents/SanjayPrusti/AngularJs/LMS-Soujanya
 /node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:109:18)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're having a hard time scoping your `it()` block, plus if you upgrade protractor, instead of using `protractor.getInstance()` you can start using `browser` syntax like this:

```
describe("holiday calendar", function() {
    // Should move this to a page object eventually:
    var holidayLinkElm = $('#holidayId');

    it('tests a non-angular page', function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    it('shows the holiday link', function() {
        expect(holidayLinkElm.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
        expect(holidayLinkElm.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('clicks holiday link', function() {
        holidayLinkElm.click();
    });

    it('switches now to an angular page', function() {
        // browser.waitForAngular() is not necessary after restoring this:
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    });

    it('validates holiday list length', function() {
        var list = element.all(by.repeater('holiday in holidayList'));
        expect(list.count()).toEqual(10);
    });
});
```